# NoReverseMatch URL not being found Django

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm probably missing something here, but I have a connect page in which the logged in user can chat to another user by clicking on a `Chat?` link located on each users profile.

The chat functionality is built using Django Channels and is accessed via the url pattern

`site/messages/username`

where username is the `other_user` that the `current_user` is chatting with.

I currently have the `chat?` link as

`<a class='btn btn-light' href="{% url 'thread' username %}" id="chat">Chat?</a>`

However that throws the error 
`NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'thread' not found. 'thread' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I have tried following the docs and adding username as an arg / taking it off but I keep hitting this same error.

The chat app is included in settings.py and the urls are included in admin.py.

The connect and chat are separate apps.

Below is relevant code. Thank you for your time and help!

chat/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import ThreadView, InboxView

app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", InboxView.as_view()),
    re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
]
```

chat/views.py

```
class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = './'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context
```

traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /connect/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/src/project/connect/views.py", line 15, in connect_home_view
    return render(request, 'connect/home.html', context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/xx/xx/project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/(?P<username>[\\w.@+-]+)']
[2019/01/27 12:36:43] HTTP GET /connect/ 500 [0.10, 127.0.0.1:50815]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `app_name = 'chat'`. This makes your app level urls available under the app namespace. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs

This should work:

```
{% url 'chat:thread' username %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my comment because I realised I hadn't added a namespace in my other apps which is why I was able to just put `thread` for example. This answer has moved me further towards resolving the problem but it throws the error `Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/(?P<username>[\\w.@+-]+)']`

Comment: @Trillz This error message means that the value of `username` is empty.

Comment: Yes you are right, I had to put user instead of username, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have given your app a name in your url  **app_name = 'chat**'
your url must have the name given

```
<a class='btn btn-light' href="{% url 'chat:thread' username %}" id="chat">Chat?</a>
```

this is called namespacing in programming

Comment: Thank you, so if I took away the namespacing `app_name='chat'` I would be able to just reference it as `thread`?

Comment: yes. but its faster with namespace because you can have another app with thread too. E.g, app_name = 'blade'.  so when you want to get the thread url in this blade app, you use "blade:thread"

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. I posted below but when I change it to `chat:thread username` I now get `Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/(?P<username>[\\w.@+-]+)'] ` Do you have any idea why it isn't finding the thread even though the pattern is correct?

Comment: The whole thing? This is the end `File "/Users/x/x/x/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'thread' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/(?P<username>[\\w.@+-]+)'] [2019/01/27 12:18:17] HTTP GET /connect/ 500 [0.08, 127.0.0.1:50464]`

Comment: edit your question and incluce the whole traceback. However, two things are likely causing it. 1- You have a url in your html page thats still pointing to the old url. 2- argument for view is not complete

Comment: I'm posting it now. I don't have any other urls pointing to the old url so 2 is most likely causing the problem.

Comment: Please add home.html page too

Comment: I've resolved it, I needed to put user instead of username!